# Wikidata SPARQL query-schema:last modified

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

Being an intern at a performing organization, an organization that imported its database in 2018, I am to update some of that data and add references to some of the properties that have been created in 2018. To do so, I need to make sure those properties were not edited by someone else to make sure of the integrity of the data that I want to make changes to. I have been trying to do this using schema: dateModified feature of sparql language in Wikidata query service. However, the data that I receive is in conflict with the items's Wikidata history page. Here is the query I have been trying out:

```
SELECT ?itemLabel ?countryLabel ?change
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P5164 ?id ;
        wdt:P17 ?country.
  ?country schema:dateModified ?change .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],nl,en". }             
}
```

I do not know where the problem is. I would appreciate any form of feedback. Thank you very much.

Comment: `?item schema:dateModified ?change`?

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. Is there a way to query whether a certain property (like the country) has changed or not?